# How to tell Bash to not stop the simulations when ssh disconnects?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, exec

I am running some simulations on another machine via `ssh`. Here is what I do

`ssh username@ipp.ip.ip.ip`

Go to the right directory

`cd path/to/folder`

And then I just call my executable

`.\myexecutable.exe`

The issue is that every time the ssh disconnect, the simulations stops. How can I make sure the simulations doesn't stop on the other machine? Will I somehow receive potential error messages (assuming the code will crash) once I reconnect (ssh)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should launch a `screen` or `tmux` to create a terminal from which you can detach, leave running in the background and later reattach.

Further reading:

- http://ss64.com/osx/screen.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screen.1.html

You may also want to try out Byobu:

- http://byobu.co

Answer (score 0):

run your command as follows : `nohup ./myexecutable.exe >nohup.out 2>&1 &`

The `&` is to run the command in the background
The `>nohup.out 2>&1` sends your stdout and stderr to `nohup.out`)

Note the '/' as opposed to '\' - which won't work on osx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I don't quite get what `nohup.out` should be. Should it be a file on my computer? Some ID of a Terminal (If the concept of Terminal ID exists)? I don't quite the numbers `2` and `1` but that might just be too advanced for me.

Comment: Doesn't `nohup` handle redirecting stdout (and stderr) to `nohup.out` automatically? Is there a need to handle the redirection manually?

Comment: nohup.out is the output from your command, 2>&1 tells it to redirect stderr to stdout

Comment: @Remi.b `nohup.out` is a filename. You can use any you want it will be created for you. See some of the questions and answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%222%3E%261%22) for more about the `2>&1` bit.

Comment: @etan - stderr no, nohup.out for clarity

Comment: Looks like it does here `nohup ls -l /proc/self/fd`. `cat nohup.out` -> `1 -> /root/nohup.out` and `2 -> /root/nohup.out` but maybe that's not always true.